# In which manvantara did Devi Durga kill Mahishasura and other demons?

Tags: devi, durga, devi-bhagavata-purana, manvantara

In which manvantara were the demons Mahishasura, Shumbha, Nishumbha and Raktabija killed?

Comment: Any particular reason you're looking for this info? Just wondering the connection

Comment: If you look up The Sanskrit Channel on YT they have explanation of this, not in terms of time but in terms of meaning of Durga killing these entities.